# Pandas get cell value by row NUMBER (NOT row index) and column NAME

Tags: python, pandas

```
data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'], index = [7,3,9])
display(df)
df.iat[0,0]
```

[image]

I'd like to return the Age in first row (basically something like df.iat[0,'Age']. Expected result = 10

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Related: "[pandas loc vs. iloc vs. at vs. iat?](/q/28757389/90527)"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`df['Age'].iloc[0]` works too, similar to what Chris had answered.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, thanks. iloc vs loc is a bit confusing...I thought that the "i" in iloc refers to index not row number, but it is the other way around! :-)

Comment: @ChadeeFouad My thinking was the same!  Overall , I wish the Pandas programmatic experience was bit more intuitive.

Answer (score 4):

Use `iloc` and `Index.get_loc`:

```
df.iloc[0, df.columns.get_loc("Age")]
```

Output:

```
10
```

Comment: Thanks...but I was looking for a straightforward command...I'm kind of surprised that it doesn't exist?

Comment: A method that may take both integer index (`iloc`) and/or name/index will be extremely vulnerable: row index with 0 is not necessarily row with integer index 0, vice versa, and so is for columns, and pandas will never know the context of user input.

Comment: well I have lots of situations where a dataframe is sorted and I just need to take values from the first row whatever it is. I guess your solution is the only way. I'll accept your answer. Thanks

Comment: @ShadyMBA If its always the first row, how about `df.head(1)["Age"]`?

Comment: That's a smart solution Chris!